# CreateNewUser and Send Verification Email

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a registration page with the following code: -

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Security" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<script runat="server">

public void CreateUser_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
  // Create new user and retrieve create status result.

  MembershipCreateStatus status;
  string passwordQuestion = "";
  string passwordAnswer = "";

  if (Membership.RequiresQuestionAndAnswer)
  {
    passwordQuestion = PasswordQuestionTextbox.Text;
    passwordAnswer = PasswordAnswerTextbox.Text;
  }

  try
  {
    MembershipUser newUser = Membership.CreateUser(UsernameTextbox.Text, PasswordTextbox.Text, 
                                                   EmailTextbox.Text, passwordQuestion,
                                                   passwordAnswer, true, out status);
    if (newUser == null)
    {
      Msg.Text = GetErrorMessage(status);
    }
    else
    {
      Response.Redirect("~/ok_reg.aspx");
    }
  }
  catch
  {
    Msg.Text = "An exception occurred creating the user.";
  }
}

public string GetErrorMessage(MembershipCreateStatus status)
{
   switch (status)
   {
      case MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateUserName:
        return "Username already exists. Please enter a different user name.";

      case MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateEmail:
        return "A username for that e-mail address already exists. Please enter a different e-mail address.";

      case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidPassword:
        return "The password provided is invalid. Please enter a valid password value.";

      case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidEmail:
        return "The e-mail address provided is invalid. Please check the value and try again.";

      case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidAnswer:
        return "The password retrieval answer provided is invalid. Please check the value and try again.";

      case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidQuestion:
        return "The password retrieval question provided is invalid. Please check the value and try again.";

      case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidUserName:
        return "The user name provided is invalid. Please check the value and try again.";

      case MembershipCreateStatus.ProviderError:
        return "The authentication provider returned an error. Please verify your entry and try again. If the problem persists, please contact your system administrator.";

      case MembershipCreateStatus.UserRejected:
        return "The user creation request has been canceled. Please verify your entry and try again. If the problem persists, please contact your system administrator.";

      default:
        return "An unknown error occurred. Please verify your entry and try again. If the problem persists, please contact your system administrator.";
   }
}

</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
<title>Create User</title>
</head>
<body>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <h3>Create New User</h3>

  <br />

  <table cellpadding="3" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td>Account ID:</td>
      <td><asp:Textbox id="UsernameTextbox" runat="server" /></td>
      <td><asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="UsernameRequiredValidator" runat="server"
                                      ControlToValidate="UserNameTextbox" ForeColor="red"
                                      Display="Static" ErrorMessage="Required" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Password:</td>
      <td><asp:Textbox id="PasswordTextbox" runat="server" TextMode="Password" /></td>
      <td><asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="PasswordRequiredValidator" runat="server"
                                      ControlToValidate="PasswordTextbox" ForeColor="red"
                                      Display="Static" ErrorMessage="Required" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Confirm Password:</td>
      <td><asp:Textbox id="PasswordConfirmTextbox" runat="server" TextMode="Password" /></td>
      <td><asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="PasswordConfirmRequiredValidator" runat="server"
                                      ControlToValidate="PasswordConfirmTextbox" ForeColor="red"
                                      Display="Static" ErrorMessage="Required" />
          <asp:CompareValidator id="PasswordConfirmCompareValidator" runat="server"
                                      ControlToValidate="PasswordConfirmTextbox" ForeColor="red"
                                      Display="Static" ControlToCompare="PasswordTextBox"
                                      ErrorMessage="Confirm password must match password." />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Email Address:</td>
      <td><asp:Textbox id="EmailTextbox" runat="server" /></td>
      <td><asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="EmailRequiredValidator" runat="server"
                                      ControlToValidate="EmailTextbox" ForeColor="red"
                                      Display="Static" ErrorMessage="Required" /></td>
    </tr>


<% if (Membership.RequiresQuestionAndAnswer) { %>

    <tr>
      <td>Password Question:</td>
      <td><asp:Textbox id="PasswordQuestionTextbox" runat="server" /></td>
      <td><asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="PasswordQuestionRequiredValidator" runat="server"
                                      ControlToValidate="PasswordQuestionTextbox" ForeColor="red"
                                      Display="Static" ErrorMessage="Required" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Password Answer:</td>
      <td><asp:Textbox id="PasswordAnswerTextbox" runat="server" /></td>
      <td><asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="PasswordAnswerRequiredValidator" runat="server"
                                      ControlToValidate="PasswordAnswerTextbox" ForeColor="red"
                                      Display="Static" ErrorMessage="Required" /></td>
    </tr>

<% } %>


    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">

  <asp:Label id="Msg" ForeColor="maroon" runat="server" /></td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
      <td><asp:Button id="CreateUserButton" Text="Create User" OnClick="CreateUser_OnClick" runat="server" /></td>
      <td><asp:Button id="PasswordRecover" Text="Password Recover"  runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/recover.aspx" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Here what i have to do is create a new user and send a verification mail to the email id provided by the user. User is being created without any problem, But I am finding bit hard to insert code for sending email id.

A little help is much appreciated. I need some guidance to send verification email to new users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The System.Net.Mail namespace contains the various classes that are related to email. You can use some of the classes to send email. More information on this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Also, it is recommended that the server-side processing code be put in the aspx.cs file (code behind) than embedding directly into the ASPX page.

Comment: thankyou for the advice. I have removed the code and added as behind.

Comment: Great! Were you able to set up the email functionality as needed?